# Microsoft Azure Server virus the all files SUFFIX update to ".wallet"

Tags: wallet

my server, the all files SUFFIX  update to ".wallet"

[image: enter image description]

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to be about programming.  Voting to close.

Comment: You have been infected with the wallet virus